# How to force a dev release of my module?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

Whenever I go to create a release for my contrib module, it gives me one option - 6.x-1.x (6.x-1.x-dev) - but if I select that it says "The version you have selected (6.x-1.x-dev) is already in use by another release." IIRC dev releases are packaged automatically every twelve hours, so why is this option even appearing? And it seems like dev releases aren't being packaged automatically for my module ...

Comment: Are you seeing the commits show up on the **Revisions** tab on the project?

Comment: See my comment below: I would have thought that the commit at http://drupalcode.org/project/csm.git/commit/b2b9979 would have triggered a new dev release, but it didn't

Answer (score 2):

In the "Release" tab of your project you've a checkbox with "Show snapshot release". If you check it, you should see the dev releases appear.

Comment: Thanks, @yvan. That box is already checked, though. Dev releases were appearing until January this year, but not any more for the 6.x branch (and there's been a full release on that branch since then, which is appearing fine)

Comment: Well have you made any commits since January?
The dev release is automatically regenerated each day if there are new commits.

Comment: I would have that that this commit - http://drupalcode.org/project/csm.git/commit/b2b9979 - would have triggered a new dev release, but it didn't